# Using ENUMS from different classes (or namespaces) for slots called from QML

Tags: qt, enums, qml, qt5

I have a class (e.g. `MyEnumClass`, `Q_GADGET`) in which I define an `enum`, e.g. `MyEnum`.
I call `Q_ENUM(MyEnum)` to register it to the metaobject, and register the whole class as uncreatable type to QML.

In my second class (`MyObject : QObject` with macro `Q_OBJECT`) I have a slot that consumes a `MyEnum` as parameter. This object is registered as regular type to QML (creatable).

I want to call the slot from QML with a value from `MyEnum` - this fails, as the Type `MyEnumClass::MyEnum` seems to be unknown.

When the enum is defined inside the class with the slot, it works fine.

---

**MVCE**

```
class MyEnumClass {
    Q_GADGET
public:
    enum MyEnum {
        E1,
        E2,
        E3
    };
    Q_ENUM(MyEnum)
};


class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyObject(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

    enum TestEnum {
        V1,
        V2,
        V3
    };
    Q_ENUM(TestEnum)

public slots:
    void testFun1(MyEnumClass::MyEnum val) { qDebug() << val; }
    void testFun2(TestEnum val) { qDebug() << val; }
};
```

in main.cpp:

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<MyEnumClass>("MyObject", 1, 0, "MyEnum", "Uncreatable");
qmlRegisterType<MyObject>("MyObject", 1, 0, "MyObject");
```

in main.qml:

```
import MyObject 1.0
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600

    MyObject {
        id: obj
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log(MyObject.V2)
            console.log(MyEnum.E2)
            obj.testFun2(MyObject.V2)
            obj.testFun1(MyEnum.E1)
        }
    }
}
```

---

I tried to inherit `MyEnumClass` in `MyObject` to make the enum part of `MyObject`, I tried with different macros and functions to make the enum even more available in the MetaObjectSystem... to no avail.

I also tried to put an enum in a namespace as described [**here**](https://www.kdab.com/new-qt-5-8-meta-object-support-namespaces/) - it was also unusable for a slot.

The only way I found to have the slot called, was by removing the enum and using int as type for the parameter - which is not that nice...

---

How can I make this work?
Are there any tricks I am missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Register metatype:

```
qRegisterMetaType<MyEnumClass::MyEnum>();
```

### Explanation:

From [Q_ENUM( ...)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_ENUM) documentation:

> This macro registers an enum type with the meta-object system. It must
>   be placed after the enum declaration in a class that has the Q_OBJECT
>   or the Q_GADGET macro. For namespaces use Q_ENUM_NS() instead.
>
> ...
>
> Registered enumerations are automatically registered also to the Qt
>   meta type system, making them known to QMetaType without the need to
>   use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE().

Using `Q_ENUM` automatically registers enum with meta-object system so you don't need to add
`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyEnum)`

But to use enum in queued signal slot connections, properties... you need to register meta type.

As said in [int qRegisterMetaType()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType) documentation:

> To use the type T in QVariant, using Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() is
>   sufficient. To use the type T in queued signal and slot connections,
>   qRegisterMetaType() must be called before the first connection is
>   established.
>
> Also, to use type T with the QObject::property() API,
>   qRegisterMetaType() must be called before it is used, typically in
>   the constructor of the class that uses T, or in the main() function.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I am surprised, since I was expecting that those are implicitly called when registering it with `qmlRegister[Uncreatable]Type` - and since they were available in QML, e.g. for `console.log()`.

Comment: I'll have to look through documentation once again to remember but if i recall correctly it has something to do with namespaces.

Comment: I was just skimming through the documentation as well, [and it seems to be reccomended to use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` for anything that is not just a `typedef`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType) - but that does not work in my production project at least...

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Eligijus Pupeikis' answer, In my case I got the following error:

```
Error: Unknown method parameter type: Parameter::Id
```

And solved it by registering the exact type name it was looking for:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Parameter::Id>("Parameter::Id");
```

where `Parameter::Id` is an `enum class` inside the `Parameter` class.